# Possibility of a closed form for $I_n = \int \frac{x^n e^{\tan^{-1}{x}}}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\text{d}x$ where $n$ is a given integer.

Tags: definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

The case of $n=2$ possesses an elementary closed form, which Mathematica 9 failed to find. This gives me an inkling of hope for the specific cases of the general form, as I have determined the existence of a recurrence relation between three consecutive integers.

$(n+1)I_{n+1} + I_n + nI_{n-1} = e^{\tan^{-1}{x}} x^n \sqrt{x^2+1} $

So I pose the following question: Does a closed form exist for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ ?

If the answer is no, then a follow up is: Does a closed form exist for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ ?

And finally, if the answers to both of those are no, then does a closed form exist for either from $-1$ to $1$, or from $0$ to $1$?

Those borders are simple values, and if either exist, I can constuct a recurrence relation for the general definite integral.

For the curious reader, the integral for $n=2$ is $\frac{1}{2}e^{\tan ^{-1}(x)}(x-1) \sqrt{x^2+1} $

Comment: It seems that it can be expressed in the [Appell function](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/AppellF1/), $$\frac{x^{1+n}}{1+n}F_1\bigl(1+n;(1-i)/2,(1+i)/2,2+n;ix,-ix\bigr).$$ A first step might be to write the integrand as $(1-ix)^{-(1-i)/2}(1+ix)^{-(1+i)/2}x^n$.

Comment: This is beautiful ! How did you find the recurrence relation (if I may ask) ?

Comment: One application of Integration By Parts.

Answer (score 0):

*This is not an answer but it is too long for a comment.*

Using a CAS, the result is
$$I_n=\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2}\right) \sqrt{x^2+1} x^n e^{\tan ^{-1}(x)} \left(1-e^{2
   i \tan ^{-1}(x)}\right)^{-n} \left(1+e^{2 i \tan ^{-1}(x)}\right)^{n+1}$$ $$
   F_1\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2};n+1,-n;\frac{3}{2}-\frac{i}{2};-e^{2 i \tan
   ^{-1}(x)},e^{2 i \tan ^{-1}(x)}\right)$$ where appears the Appell hypergeometric function of two variables (as already mentioned by mickep.

A further simplication could be done taking into account $$\frac{1+e^{2 i \tan ^{-1}(x)}}{1-e^{2 i \tan ^{-1}(x)}}=\frac ix$$ This goes in the same direction as mickep commented about a transform of the integrand.